# Expandable List View Android Dropdown Alignment

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an application with an `ExpandableListView` as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This `ExpandableListView` is initialized with the following code inside the `onCreate` method of an activity that extends `ExpandableListActivity`.

```
ExpandableListView expandableView = getExpandableListView();

expandableView.setIndicatorBounds(width - GetDipsFromPixel(50), width - GetDipsFromPixel(10));  

expandableView.setAdapter(new DataExpAdaptor(this, _currentDate.getTimeInMillis(), _isShowAddress));

expandableView.setOnItemLongClickListener(handleItemLongClicks);
```

This has until recently been working fine on our the Galaxy S3 mini but since updating to a newer version of the Galaxy S4 Mini (Android 4.4.2) & Galaxy S5 (Android 5.0)) the list view is now left aligning the dropdown items when this previously was right aligned.

I need to support both the existing hardware (Galaxy S3 Mini's) and the newer hardware but cant seem to set the alignment of the dropdown boxes. It doesn't matter left or right aligned, I just need to reliably know one way or the other?

**Galaxy S3 Right Align**

[image: Galaxy S3 Right Align]

---

**Galaxy S4 Left Align**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think that icon is set by default and you cant do anything. But you can hide it by putting below line in xml,

```
android:groupIndicator="@null"
```

and now in the xml of GroupHeader you can put your own icon...
Let me know if that works for you...
Hope that helps...

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was able to bypass this issue by detecting the current version of android and sorting the alignment appropriately as per the version. I didn't really want the hassle of replacing the image on the list view as mentioned above, but it was my Plan B.

Answer (score 0):

Please share the code, where you set up the ExpandableListView. There is a huge difference between indicator at the end and indicator at the Right, because of RTL support. If you are using End, then switch it to Right

Comment: Updated question with further information. I didn't know if you wanted the layout info or the code initialisation?